# updating data from mysql in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is my code. There's is a "Edit" link. I want to update data and save with that link

```
    $op_sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users"; 
    $result = $con->query($op_sql); 
    if ($result->rowCount() > 0) 
    { 

    echo "<table class='table' style='margin-left: 301px; margin-top: 10px; background-color: white;'>-; 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<th>ID</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Name</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Email</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Date of Birth<th>"; 
    echo "<th></th>"; echo "</tr>"; 
    while($row = $result->fetch())
    { 

    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $rowrID1 . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Email']. "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Date of Birth'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='?id=".$row['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
    } 
    echo "</table>"; unset($result);
```

Comment: whats the problem??

Comment: share your code in here not an image .It'll be easy to work on and analyse.

Comment: post your code here insted of image

Comment: there is a lots of answer for this type of question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819754/update-mysql-database-with-php

Comment: It would better if you share the problem.. All we understand is this is your code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `user_edit.php` url in anchor tag `href` to edit the user details like this.

```
echo "<td><a href='user_edit.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

**user_edit.php**

Here you can get the id of specific user and get the details from database and create update form like this.

```
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!='')
    {
        $op_sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users where id=$_GET['id']"; 
        $result = $con->query($op_sql); 
        if ($result->rowCount() > 0) 
        {  
            $row = $result->fetch();
        ?>
           <form action="user_update.php" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php $row['Name'] ?>" />
           .
           .
           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$_GET['id']" />
           .
           .
           <input type="submit" name="update" value="update" />

        <?php

        }
    }
```

**user_update.php**

Here you can get the updated form data and update in database

```
    if(isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!='' )
    {

        // here you can get the updated form data and update in database 

        // update user set Name=$_POST['Name'],.... where id=$_POST['id'];

    }
```

**NOTE :**

> Try to use Prepared statement or PDO

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick its useful for future user reference .@KhantZin

Answer (score 1):

I am giving an answer from [This question you can use the same answer in your context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535604/update-a-table-of-information-on-a-button-click) here I'm providing the code from the accepted answer.

You can use a get method here in place of the post according to your situation.

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">

    <button type="submit" name="passed" id="passed" class="btn btn-success btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
    <button type="submit" name="insufficient" id="insufficient" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

// db connection

if(isset($_POST['passed'])){

    $allowed = mysqli_query($conn," UPDATE users SET Access = "1" WHERE id = '27' ");

}

if(isset($_POST['insufficient'])){

    $notallowed = mysqli_query($conn," UPDATE users SET Access = "0" WHERE id = '453' ");

}
```

- Be careful if this has any user interaction at any given point.
- Use [**a prepared statement**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Comment: Ok. Thank!! I'll try with this.